# mCustomScrollbar script for everypage

Tags: jquery

```
$(".text").(mCustomScrollbar({
        theme:"dark-thin",
        advanced:{
            autoScrollOnFocus:false,
            updateOnContentResize:true,
            updateOnBrowserResize:true
        }
    });
```

I have page use mCustomScrollbar & this page also use jquery **load another page** into it.
my question is how to set delegate mCustomScrollbar for everypage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have all the elements that you want with the scrollbar to be on the same class then place that piece of code you have in an external .js file.

it should be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".text").delegate("click", function({
        $(this).mCustomScrollbar({
                theme:"dark-thin",
                advanced:{
                    autoScrollOnFocus:false,
                    updateOnContentResize:true,
                    updateOnBrowserResize:true
                }
        });
});
});
```

then load the .js script in your parent page (the one that uses the jquery.load) like this:

```
<script src="blabla.js"></script>
```

NOTE: If you are using jQuery 1.7+, use .on() instead of delegate().

Comment: what im asking is when jquery load external page into parent's page, the script is not apply to external page

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want it to be not applied on elements outside the parent's page. Correct?

Comment: then try my solution. Place the function you have in an external .js file and have all the elements that you want that scrollbar in as "class='text'"

Comment: is possible to apply delegate? i dont know how to apply this in this case

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? If you're using 1.7+, then use .on() instead.

Answer (score 0):

mCustomScrollbar always call http://ajax.googleapis.com/

if you search into jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js you will see :

```
<script src="'+a+'//
```

that refer into

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so you need call the script above in everypage (diret into http://ajax.googleapis.com/)

because jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js call another jquery in their script

and you need add another external js that call function below

```
$("***your class or your id***").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"dark-thin"});
```

and call your external js function every you want this customscrollbar used.

sample :

i use this custom scrollbar in multiple div in my html

so i write external js (eg: ayam.js)

> function content1 () {
>   $(".content1").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"dark-thin"});
>   }

so every i call another div i call onclick="content1"

sorry in my bad english, im from indonesia :) thanks